# wordpressの自作テーマで、投稿記事の説明文を改行したい。

Tags: php, wordpress

## 前提・実現したいこと

wordpressの自作テーマを作成しております。
Topページの投稿記事一覧にて記事タイトル下に表示される”記事の最初の数行”を改行したいです。

## 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

「投稿を編集」の画面で改行を入れても、反映されない。

## 該当のソースコード

PHP

```
<div class="box">
<h2>出勤情報</h2>
<p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
<p>日時：<?php the_time('Y年n月j日'); ?></p>
<p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
</div>
```

[image: コード画面]

## 現在の画面と理想とする状況

現在
[image: 現在の表示]
[image: 投稿編集画面]

理想
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

`<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`
を
`<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>`
変更することで解決いたしました。

質問をご覧になって頂き、ありがとうございました！！